# What does it mean when a purple dashed line is displayed over the child elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `<div>` container with the position set to `absolute` in order to display it over the screen when open. Inside, I have a child `<div>` which serves as the main modal. When I hover over to inspect the child element, a purple dashed line is displayed over it. However, when I also add the `absolute` position to the child element, the purple dashed line disappears. What is the significance of the purple dashed line?
[image: child after add the "obsolute" position to it]

I also searched for the purpose of the purple dashed line and found that it indicates the available spaces of the . However, I am unsure of its significance when it is displayed over an element.

Answer (score 1):

> The purple dashed line you are referring to is most likely the "layout highlight" feature in the developer tools of modern web browsers. This feature is commonly found in the Inspect Element tool and is used to visualize the layout of HTML elements on the page.When you have a parent  container with position: absolute, it means that the container is taken out of the normal document flow and positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor (if any). If there is no positioned ancestor, it will be positioned relative to the initial containing block, which is usually the viewport.When you inspect the child  inside the absolute-positioned parent, you will see the purple dashed line outlining the parent container. This dashed line represents the boundary of the parent container and indicates its position and dimensions on the screen.However, when you add the position: absolute property to the child  as well, it means that the child element is also taken out of the normal document flow and positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor (which, in this case, is the parent ). This effectively means that the child element will have the same position as the parent, and the dashed line disappears because the layout highlight no longer needs to show a separate boundary for the child element—it is occupying the same position and dimensions as the parent.In summary, the purple dashed line indicates the available space and layout of an element in relation to its parent or positioned ancestor. When you set both the parent and the child elements to have position: absolute, they will overlap each other in the same position, and the dashed line will only be shown around the parent element, as it represents the combined layout of both elements.